# ethereum makes extra space for no reason in memory

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;


contract C {
    function test3(uint f) external  returns(uint256[3] memory) {
        uint256[3] memory arr;
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = 2;
        arr[2] = 3;
        return arr;
    }
}


contract A {

    function test(C addr) external returns(uint) {
        uint256[3] memory  z =addr.test3(31);
        return z[0] + z[1] + z[2];
    }
    
}
```

I have the following code. I looked at memory before and after the `call` opcode is used. Here is the difference..

https://www.diffchecker.com/NZtopQv4

If you see on this link , it's very strange. The second snippet in the link is after the `call` code is executed, meaning that returned value is put in the caller's contract's memory, but from `0x80` to `0xd0`, the bytes are still zero and the array got stored from `0xe0` to `0x130`.

So, why did it create `0x80` to `0xd0` for no reason ?  I see that it might have created it for `z` variable before it would call `call` opcode, but then, it then put the returned value in different memory space. Is Solidity Stupid ?